# How to fix this SSL Warning server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Tags: ssl, warnings

```
[ssl:warn] [pid 4122] AH01707: ip-xxx-xx-x-x.abcd.compute.internal:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

Hello,

I can't figure out what generates this warning and how to fix it.

Website is running on AWS servers.

Answer (score 5):

This happen due to server name on certificate does not matches with the server name defined in the webserver configuration. To resolve this you can change the server name to localhost in your webserver configuration.

`ServerName abc.com ----> ServerName localhost`

Ref: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/xampp-server-certificate-does-not-include-an-id-which-matches-the-server-name/

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to the .htaccess file.

It's important to note that comments should not be placed in the middle of a line in the htaccess file, they should always be start from the new line.